# Possible for Enum Integer Cast Exception?

Tags: c#, casting, enums

Given the code below, is there any possiblity the `int` cast could throw an exception?

```
        static void foo(Type typeEnum)
        {
            if (typeEnum.IsEnum)
            {
                foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeEnum))
                {
                    var _val = (int)enumVal;                      
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `GetValues` returns an array. Implicitly typing could mean the compiler will choose `object` which can't be directly cast to `int`.  Why not remove the implicit `var` and save yourself the headache?

Comment: @Jim: Removing the implicit typing won't save him.  It will throw on the cast in the `foreach` then.  You *can* cast from `object` to `int` as long as the `object` is truly boxing an `int`, just can't do a conversion cast.

Comment: @Jim in foreach loops explicitly typed loop variables are even more dangerous than `var`. The compiler will happily insert casts that would normally be explicit and can fail at runtime without telling you. In particular in this case using an `int` iteration variable will compile and fail at runtime in the same cases in which this code fails. [Once again the lack of generics in .net 1 caused warts in C#]

Comment: I have to ask the reason you are casting the emumeration, **_val** is not used at all, it serves no purpose, the only way it could cause an exception is if the enumVal cannot be casted to an integer.

Comment: @Ramhound - its just example code to illustrate my question clearly.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I wasn't thinking of the 'any possibility' remark as referring to enums that inherit from anything other than `int`. In that case, I'd do as James does in his answer and use `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the `enum` backing type is not `int`, like:

```
    public enum X : long
    {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }
```

This will throw.  This is because the `enum` values are boxes as `object`, and you can't cast 'object' to 'int' unless the contained value is actually an 'int'.

You could alleviate this by doing a `Convert.ToInt32()` which will work for all backing types of `int` or smaller:

```
static void foo(Type typeEnum)
{
    if (typeEnum.IsEnum)
    {
        foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeEnum))
        {
            var _val = Convert.ToInt32(enumVal);                      
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to assume `int` and just be safer, you can check the underlying type of the `enum` like:

```
if (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeEnum) != typeof(int))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("This method only accepts int enums.");
}
```

Alternatively, you could assume a type of `long` if signed or `ulong` if unsigned (you can have negative `enum` values, but tend to be rarer):

```
static void foo(Type typeEnum)
{
    if (typeEnum.IsEnum)
    {
        foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeEnum))
        {
            var _val = Convert.ToInt64(enumVal);                      
        }
    }
}
```

This is why it's probably safer to make some assumptions and check them on the call.  Anything you do to unbox the value has the potential of throwing or overflowing.

You could even go generic and have the user pass in the type they want to get out:

```
static IEnumerable<ToType> foo<ToType>(Type typeEnum)
{
    if (typeEnum.IsEnum)
    {
        foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeEnum))
        {
            yield return (ToType)Convert.ChangeType(enumVal, typeof(ToType));
        }
    }
}
```

So you could invoke this:

```
IEnumerable<int> values foo<int>(typeof(YourEnum));
```

Then if they get an exception, it falls on them to specify the right size type...

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` can still throw an `OverflowException` if the enum's value is too big to fit in an `int`.

Comment: @Stephen: Of course, but it would get around the casting issue.  At that point it's up to the OP to decide what to do.  My suggestion is to either check for non `int` enum types, or the OP can always return a `long`.

Comment: +1 For the type conversion method. I've used a very similar extension method to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Enums are strange beasts. They may inherit from long and still be enums.

I'm pretty sure this theoretical code would throw a cast exception should you take an enum that does this.

Answer (score 0):

As James Michael Hare mentioned, enums can be `long`s.  However, using `Convert.ToInt32` is not good enough because you could still get an overflow exception.  Imagine the following enum that has a value that is bigger than can even fit in an int:

```
public enum BigEnum : long
{
    BigValue = (long)int.MaxValue + 5
}
```

In that case, there is no way to convert that value to an `int` because it is too big.  However, you can use logic like this and it will not throw:

```
static void foo(Type typeEnum)
{
    var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeEnum);

    if (typeEnum.IsEnum)
    {
        foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues(typeEnum))
        {
            var _val = Convert.ChangeType(enumVal, underlyingType);
        }
    }
}
```

It uses the [`Enum.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype.aspx) method which ensures that the call to `ChangeType` will be working with the correct type.  (in fact, that MSDN page for GetUnderlyingType has sample code that does almost this exact thing my sample code does).

Comment: Unfortunately, that just removes the issue back one level.  He'd have a value boxed in an `object` (ChangeType returns `object`) that he can't cast back to `int` or `long` directly.  Essentially, all this does is convert the boxed `long` back into a boxed `long` and leaves him in the same situation.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare I was just answering the OP's question perhaps too literally.  He asked if the int cast could throw.  It can.  And so can a call to Convert.ToInt32.  But yes, it all depends on what _val is to be used for.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum.GetValues` actually returns an array of that particular enum type.

What's not mentioned is that the particular array is also castable to `int[]` if `TEnum:int` or `TEnum:uint` (CLR arrays for primitives are convertible regardless of signedness)
Otherwise to be defensive you can always use the `Convert.ChangeType(object,Type)` api to be safe.
As a result you can write your code to be like so:

```
    static void foo(Type typeEnum)
    {
        if (typeEnum.IsEnum)
        {
            var array = Enum.GetValues(typeEnum)
            int[] arrayAsInts = array as int[];
            if(arrayAsInts != null)
            { 
              foreach (var enumVal in arrayAsInts)
              {
                 var _val = enumVal;                      
              }
            }
            else
            {
              foreach (var enumVal in array)
              {
                 var _val = Convert.ChangeType(enumVal,typeof(int));                      
              }
            }
        }
    }
```